# How to manage multi-tab form with React, Redux and Redux saga?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-saga, antd

I'm working in a CRM with React, Redux and Redux-Saga. 
I looking for a nice/scalable way to update and save data with deep data structure maintaining a good UI.

Let's assume that I want to edit a basic Product model:

```
state : {
title: "Test title",
description: "Test title",
name: "Test title",
variants: [],
gallery: []

}
```

The UI has one parent component that contains 3 children tabs with forms and inputs for updating: Descriptions (title, description, name), variants and gallery.

The submit button is inside the parent component, so the user can save the product regardless of the tab in which it is located.

The question is: when the user press "save", what is the best way to pass the state of every children tab to the parent? Before launching the save api, we have to wait until all states are passed to the parent. How to do that?

I've tried to accomplish that task connecting all children tabs with the product store, when the user press the save button, I will dispatch an action to the product store that will fire all connected children "componentDidUpdate" method. In every children "componentDidUpdate" method, I'm putting the children current state to the equivalent key in the product store, and after that, I will fire the saveProduct saga. It seems that work, but is async, so the saveProduct saga is fired before all states are stored in the product store.

```
// ProductEdit.js

//Parent component example

@connect(({ product }) => ({ product }))
class ProductEdit extends React.Component {

    onSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault()
        const { dispatch, product } = this.props

        //All sub components will listen for this action, 
        //when launched all states have to be put into the store
        dispatch({
            type: 'product/STATE_TO_STORE_ACTION',
            payload: {
                action: 'state_to_store'
            }
        });

    }

    render() {

        <div>
            <Tabs defaultActiveKey="Descriptions">
                <TabPane
                    tab="Descriptions"
                    key="Descriptions"
                >
                    <DescriptionForm />
                </TabPane>
                <TabPane
                    tab="Variants"
                    key="Product Variants"
                >
                    <VariantsForm />
                </TabPane>
                <TabPane
                    tab="Gallery"
                    key="Gallery"
                >
                    <GalleryForm />
                </TabPane>
            </Tabs>

            <Button onClick={this.onSubmit}>Save</Button>

        </div>
    }
}

//Children component 1 example
@connect(({ product }) => ({ product }))
class DescriptionForm extends React.Component {

    state = {
        title: "",
        description: "",
        name: ""
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
        //Get the product store from props
        const { product } = this.props

        if (product.action == 'state_to_store')

            dispatch({
                type: 'product/SET_STATE',
                payload: {
                    action: 'state_to_store_updated',
                    item: {

                        title: this.state.title,
                        description: this.state.description,
                        name: this.state.name,
                    }
                }
            });
    }

    render() {
        /*...*/
    }
}

//Children component 2 example
@connect(({ product }) => ({ product }))
class VariantsForm extends React.Component {

    state = {
        variants: []
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
        //Get the product store from props
        const { product } = this.props

        if (product.action == 'state_to_store')

            dispatch({
                type: 'product/SET_STATE',
                payload: {
                    action: 'state_to_store_updated',
                    item: {
                        variants: this.state.variants
                    }
                }
            });
    }

    render() {
        /*...*/
    }
}

/* ...AND SO ON... */
```